# Angular dynamic Template Injection

Tags: angular

I'm learning the ropes on angular and chanced upon an interesting though when creating my test application. What I'm trying to achieve is to dynamically load the template (`loadPizzaMenu` or `loadPizzaAdmin` using the template expression ) dynamically based on a value in my component.ts
using a template expression using the value `pizzaLoader`. I tried adding interpolation to the template ref which threw a compilation error thus.

`<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="{{ pizzaLoader }}"></ng-container>`

How would i achieve this programmatically if the above is not valid? The follow naturally works as the template refs are hardcoded:

**component.ts**

`pizzaLoader = 'loadPizzaMenu' ? user.isUser : 'loadPizzaAdmin'`

**template**
`<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="loadPizzaMenu"></ng-container>`

```
<ng-template #loadPizzaMenu>
      <pizza></pizza>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #loadPizzaAdmin>
      <pizza></pizza>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your source code to

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user.isUser; then loadPizzaAdmin else loadPizzaMenu"></ng-container>
```

[stackBlitz Answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/questions58514584)

Hope this will helps ...!

Comment: think you forgot to add the meat my friend :O

Comment: sorry friend, check it now